# Strategy for worker addressing

Tags: python, celery

I have an application which is delegating some operations to a celery task. The operations must be performed by different workers, depending on some parameters. I have thought about implementing this using queues. My idea is the following:

1. The client requests actions from a specific message `queue1`
2. If `worker1` (exclusively responsible for `queue1`) is already active, it will process the request
3. If no worker is listening to `queue1`, a catch-all worker (`worker-main`) will instantiate `worker1`. The request will be forwared to `worker1`.
4. `worker1` will shut itself down after some time without being used

My understanding of celery is limited, and I have several questions.

1. **How do I implement `worker-main` in celery?**: this is a worker listening to all queues, but with less priority than any other worker. That is, it will only act if the request is not taken by any other worker.
2. **How does `woker-main` create `worker1`?** Once creater, `worker1` must be associated to `queue1`, with higher precendence than `worker-main`?
3. **Can a request be forwarded from `worker-main`to `worker1`?** The reply should be sent to the client directly.
4. **Can `worker1` shut itself down?**

You can see a graphical description of the architecture that I am trying to implement in the image below:

[image: multi-worker]

Answer (score 1):

You could link together "worker main" and "worker1" in a sequential workflow so that "worker main" always handles the job as step 1, but simply returns and does nothing if it detects that "worker1" is already up.

So the task hits "worker main" first, "worker main" checks for upness of the server that worker1 is running on, and if that server is not up, pulls it up, waits for it to be fully up and then returns. Here is a [proof of concept](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/how-to-create-a-sequential-workflow-with-error-handling-in-celery) I tested to see how link worked in Celery to create a sequential workflow, somebody with more real-world experience may have better solutions. It also contains error handling, in case getting the worker up fails I suppose in your case.

Note that there is no concept of queues in this approach. Furthermore, you could give worker1 and worker2 different method names instead of differentiating on parameters, the client can do the parsing of parameters and then select celery method to execute.

Comment: I am not sure this is what I need. In my case, the celery task must be running and the workers must be created from **within** the task. No user intervention *and* no shell commands. The  worker pool can grow very large, eventually on the 100s of workers, each one listening to a different queue. As you say, the addressing must not necessarily be queue-based: I just need a way to send messages to a certain worker, and a way for the catch-all worker to realize that the worker is missing and to create the worker on the fly.

Comment: Also: I am not talking about a single task. The client can request different tasks from the worker (currently I have over 30 different tasks that need to be performed by the worker). All those task requests must be sniffed by the `worker-main`, and if `worker1` (`worker2`, ...) is not running, it must be instantiated, and the task request forwarded.